# If second derivative is negative then it is concave

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, geometry

Some people might use the second derivative as the definition of a concave function.
But I think the intuitive definition is that graph is above the line joining two points of the graph for arbitrary two points.

Although, By pictorially, it seems that two definitions are equivalent. BUT how to prove that two are?

Comment: Note that the second definition is the actual definition of concavity, and can handle non-differentiable functions. But, for differentiable functions, the two are equivalent. I think the usual approach is to use yet another equivalent definition: tangent lines to the graph lie above the graph. There is also some result about slopes of secant lines are decreasing, like $\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a} \ge \frac{f(c)-f(a)}{c-a}$ for $a<b<c$ or something.

Comment: A function $f$ is concave on an interval $[a,b]$ if for any $x,y \in [a,b]$, for any $\lambda \in [0,1]$, the following inequality: $$\lambda f(x) + (1-\lambda)f(y) \leqslant f(\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y)$$ holds. Can you use this for you proof?

Comment: Proofs can be found on the web in various places—[here, for example](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Second_Derivative_of_Strictly_Concave_Real_Function_is_Strictly_Negative) (clicking on the links in the proof to fill in full details).

Comment: @angryavian Thank you. I can prove it.

Comment: If you want to work from the definition you have been given alone, it is enough to assume strictly convex, and assume for contradiction there is a triplet $x,y,\lambda$ so that $>$ holds. Then continuity guarantees you can choose $x$ and $y$ arbitrarily close together, which implies $f'(p) < 0$ and $f'(q) > 0$ for some $p,q \in [a,b]$, and continuity of $f'$ yields $f''(0) = 0$, a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

let $x_1 \leq x_2$ and $\alpha \in [0,1]$. Since we know that $f''(x_1)\leq 0$ if and only if $\frac{f(x_2) - f(x_1)}{x_2 - x_1}\leq \frac{f(y) - f(x_1)}{y - x_1}$  where $y = (1-\alpha)x_1 + \alpha x_2$.